# How to use drop down widget in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, dropdown

I am trying to add dropdown button to widget, but it show me only the button, without labels or textinput. After close APP it show me second widget with all stuff. 
Where am i making a mistake? 
Well thank you

My noob code:

main.py:

```
class MyGrid(FloatLayout):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    psc = ObjectProperty(None)


def btn(self):
    self.clear_btn()

def clear_btn(self):
    self.email.text = ""

class MyApp(App): # <- Main Class
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()

dropdown = DropDown()
for index in range(10):

    btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)

    btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))

    dropdown.add_widget(btn)


mainbutton = Button(text='Hello', size_hint=(None, None))

mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))

runTouchApp(mainbutton)
```

my kv.file:

```
<MyGrid>:
    Label:
        text: "Email: "

    TextInput:
        id: email
        multiline:False


    Button:
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.11}
        text:"Send"
        on_press: root.btn()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

runs your `MyApp`, and that does not return until `MyApp` closes. So the code after that does not get run until `MyApp` closes, and then

```
runTouchApp(mainbutton)
```

starts another `App`. You probably want the code that creates the `DropDown` inside a class somewhere (maybe `MyGrid`), and add the `mainbutton` to the gui (maybe in `MyGrid`).

Comment: Yes you right. I want it inside a class MyGrid. But my skill is really low and I dont know how to add the mainbutton to MyGrid. When I add there runTouchApp(mainbutton), it didnt solve my problem. Anyway thanks :)